# Adding Timeout to Asynchronous Calls in Java

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, firebase

Not solely a Firebase question, but I am using Firebase to make posts to a backend from Android and run it 10 times, once every second.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(URL);
ref.child("Time").setValue(Currentime());
```

However this is an Asynchronous Call and when I put a while loop:

```
while (time_now < time_start + 10 seconds) {
     Firebase ref = new Firebase(URL);
     ref.child("Time").setValue(Currentime());
}
```

It seems to run the while loop first and then ~10 Firebase calls at the end. Is there a way to add a timeout so that it forces the Asynchronous (Firebase) calls to run for a second before calling the next Async call?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for?  Specifically, are you saying that the loop runs for about 10 times in a row very rapidly - say, within one second - and you want them to kick off more slowly, at intervals of one second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Java example on the Firebase web site](https://www.firebase.com/docs/transactions.html#java), you'll see that it has a `doTransactions` method and an `onComplete` method:

```
Firebase countRef = new Firebase(URL);
Transaction.Handler handler = new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
        // set the new time
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError error, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        if (error != null) {
            ...
        } else {
            if (!committed) {
                ...
            } else {
                // transaction committed, do next iteration
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
});
countRef.runTransaction(handler);
```

So you'd set the new time in the `doTransaction` method:

```
// set the new time
currentData.setValue(time_now);
return Transaction.success(currentData);
```

And then start a next iteration in the `onComplete` method.

```
// transaction committed, do next iteration
if (time_now < time_start + 10 seconds) {
    countRef.runTransaction(handler);
}
```